# Cant purge with apt-get, because of dependencies

Tags: boot, apt, kernel, purge

My `/boot/` sadly is full, so I cant use `apt-get upgrade` anymore, or similar things.

If I try to purge one of the kernels, with:

`apt-get purge linux-image-3.2.0-29-generic`

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-server : Depends: linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.41.49) but 3.2.0.48.58 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And nothing happens after all. I cant use `apt-get -f install`, since the action fails due to a full `/boot/`. How can I force `apt-get` to delete one of the images?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an older thread :

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1587462

You could use tweak or synaptic for to remove some of the older kernels.

I would let at least one older kernel of your choice "alive" - cause then you are safe for to boot for sure - in case the newest kernel does not work right after update, or after being malformed somehow.

Comment: The problem is, I dont have a GUI, and neither synaptic or tweak installed (it's a remote server)

Comment: @user169099 here is a possibility how to do it from terminal: http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2011/01/08/ubuntu-cleanup-how-to-remove-all-unused-linux-kernel-headers-images-and-modules/

Comment: same problem as before - it stops midway, telling me that I have dependencies. I dont get it, why cant I just force apt to remove that thing, ignoring the dependencies (that have nothing to do with the old kernels anyways, since that error comes when I try to delete ANY kernel). I cant install, I cant upgrade, I cant remove. I'm stuck - I just need to 'force' the command...

Comment: @user169099 You already tried: sudo apt-get autoremove ?

Comment: same thing - I always get the same error, no matter what apt-get command I give - it always tells me that I have to try out `apt-get -f install` - but that command fails too, since /boot/ is full

Comment: @user169099 - this is clear now ! when /boot/ is an own partition and restricted to certain size, then you have to remove older kernels there. Here are two commands - one to find out, which versions are installed and the second command to purge the older kernels safely. Watch out for the matching version:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/334976/safe-to-remove-old-kernels-after-installing-latest-mainline